# How to show values under the slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, information-visualization

I'm working on an information visualisation project and currently trying to add values to the slider. However, it didn't function so far. The slider itself works fine, but there seems no value under the slider in the webpage. I want to have dates such as 2021-12-15 under the slider, how can make this work? Here's the code that I'd worked on so far, thanks in advance!

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="12" value="12" class="slider" id="mySlider">
</div>

<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("mySlider");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
</script>

function slider_Update(binNumber) {
    new_date = formatTime(new Date("2008-"+binNumber+"-01"));
      let checked_group = ".";
      let count = 1;
      // For each checkbox:
    d3.selectAll(".checkbox").each(function(d){
        const cb = d3.select(this);
        const grp = cb.property("value");
        //console.log(cb.property("checked")+" "+cb.property("value"));
      // If the box is check, add to checked_group, else hide
      if(cb.property("checked")){
        if(count===1){
          checked_group += grp;
          count++;
          //console.log(checked_group+"  count: "+count);
        }else{
          checked_group += ",."+grp;
          //count++;
          //console.log(checked_group+"  count: "+count);
        }
      }
    })
    //change opacity for created group
    update_Worldmap(checked_group);
    update_BarPlot();
  }

  //Slider source
  //https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/density_slider.html
  // Listen to the slider
  d3.select("#mySlider").on("change", function(d){
    selectedValue = this.value
      slider_Update(selectedValue)
    //console.log("from mySldier select: "+selectedValue)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element with id `demo` in your HTML. You should do something like this:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("mySlider");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="12" value="12" class="slider" id="mySlider" />
  <div id="demo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However, I actually wanted to have something like on this slider, do you know how can I make something similar?https://www.jquery-az.com/jquery/demo.php?ex=46.0_1

Comment: @AndreaBerger Which label/values on the example slider are you talking about, the scale below it or the current sider value about it, which moves with the slider pointer/knob.

Comment: I'd actually like to implement both of them

Answer (score 1):

how about we create new element and output new_date to that element

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="12" value="12" class="slider" id="mySlider">
    <div id="slideDate"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("mySlider");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }


function slider_Update(binNumber) {
    var new_date = formatTime(new Date("2008-"+binNumber+"-01"));
      let checked_group = ".";
      let count = 1;
      // For each checkbox:
    d3.selectAll(".checkbox").each(function(d){
        const cb = d3.select(this);
        const grp = cb.property("value");
        //console.log(cb.property("checked")+" "+cb.property("value"));
      // If the box is check, add to checked_group, else hide
      if(cb.property("checked")){
        if(count===1){
          checked_group += grp;
          count++;
          //console.log(checked_group+"  count: "+count);
        }else{
          checked_group += ",."+grp;
          //count++;
          //console.log(checked_group+"  count: "+count);
        }
      }
    })
    //change opacity for created group
    update_Worldmap(checked_group);
    update_BarPlot();
    $("#mySlider").html(new_date)
  }

  //Slider source
  //https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/density_slider.html
  // Listen to the slider
  d3.select("#mySlider").on("change", function(d){
    selectedValue = this.value
    slider_Update(selectedValue)
    //console.log("from mySldier select: "+selectedValue)
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to output the value of the slider you can add a div like this:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("mySlider");
var output = document.getElementById("slidertext");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

console.log(output);

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
    slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }

function slider_Update(binNumber) {
    new_date = formatTime(new Date("2008-"+binNumber+"-01"));
      let checked_group = ".";
      let count = 1;
      // For each checkbox:
    d3.selectAll(".checkbox").each(function(d){
        const cb = d3.select(this);
        const grp = cb.property("value");
        //console.log(cb.property("checked")+" "+cb.property("value"));
      // If the box is check, add to checked_group, else hide
      if(cb.property("checked")){
        if(count===1){
          checked_group += grp;
          count++;
          //console.log(checked_group+"  count: "+count);
        }else{
          checked_group += ",."+grp;
          //count++;
          //console.log(checked_group+"  count: "+count);
        }
      }
    })
    //change opacity for created group
    update_Worldmap(checked_group);
    update_BarPlot();
  }

  //Slider source
  //https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/density_slider.html
  // Listen to the slider
  d3.select("#mySlider").on("change", function(d){
    selectedValue = this.value
      slider_Update(selectedValue)
    //console.log("from mySldier select: "+selectedValue)
  })
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="12" value="12" class="slider" id="mySlider">
</div>
<div id = "slidertext"></div>
```

For the date part can you provide more information about what the slider needs to do? It has to change the whole date? Only the months? Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).